Log JPA transaction duration
Is there a way to intercept JPA's start / commit / rollback transaction to trigger some behavior? More specifically, I would like to ensure that my transactions are "short-lived", and if a transaction takes over 1s from start to commit, I would like to log a warning.
I was thinking of doing some AOP on @Transactional but I'm also using transactionOperations.execute(status -> { ... }) and that wouldn't work there.

The easiest way is to write a TransactionExecutionListener. You can create one which logs the time, counts etc. and you can simply add it to your JpaTransactionManager. No need for additional AOP code or other callbacks and will work for anything that uses the PlatformTransactionManager.
NOTE: This class was introduced in Spring 6.1 so if you are on an older version this won't work.
public class TimingTransactionListener implements TransactionExecutionListener {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimingTransactionListener.class);
  private final ThreadLocal<Long> startTime = new ThreadLocal<>();
  
  @Override
  public void beforeBegin(TransactionExecution transaction) {
    startTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
  }

  @Override
  public void afterCommit(TransactionExecution transaction, Throwable commitFailure) {
    logTransactionCompletion(transaction, commitFailure);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterRollback(TransactionExecution transaction, Throwable rollbackFailure) {
    logTransactionCompletion(transaction, rollbackFailure);
  }
  
  private void logTransactionCompletion(TransactionExecution transaction, Throwable failure) {
    var success = failure == null;
    var time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.get();
    startTime.remove();
    if (time > 1000) {
      log.warn("Transaction '{}' took '{}ms', rollback: {}.", transaction.getTransactionName(), time, success);
    } else {
      log.info("Transaction '{}' took '{}ms', rollback: {}.", transaction.getTransactionName(), time, success);
    }
  }
}

Next you can configure your JpaTransactionManager.
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
  var transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
  transactionManager.addListener(new TimingTransactionListener());
  return transactionManager;
}

If you are in the ability to use Spring Boot the only thing you need to do is register the TimingTransactionListener as a bean and Spring Boot will automatically wire it to the pre-configured PlatformTransactionManager.
Ideally you wouldn't do this logging yourself but you would integrate with a library like MicroMeter and collect metrics with something like Prometheus. You can then get more insights and create alerts based on those metrics.

The easiest way to do this is to use aspect-oriented programming to intercept transactional method calls to determine how long they take to execute:
@Aspect
@Component
public class TransactionTimeAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionTimeAspect.class);

    @Around("@within(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public Object measureTransactionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        LOGGER.info("Transaction duration: {} ms", duration);
        return result;
    }
}

A more labor-intensive way is to register a transaction completion handler:
@Component
public class TransactionDurationTracker {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionDurationTracker.class);

    public void trackTransaction() {
        if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization() {
                @Override
                public void afterCompletion(int status) {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long duration = endTime - startTime;
                    LOGGER.info("Transaction duration: {} ms", duration);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

But this method will require calling trackTransaction() inside each transaction.
Finally, Spring 6.1 introduces the TransactionExecutionListener interface, which allows you to hook into transaction lifecycle events. You simply create your own Spring component implementing this interface, and you can add logic to your application that will be executed before and after the transaction.
@Component
public class TransactionDurationListener implements TransactionExecutionListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionDurationListener.class);

    private final ThreadLocal<Long> startTime = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void beforeBegin(TransactionExecution transaction) {
        startTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCommit(TransactionExecution transaction, Throwable commitFailure) {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime.get();
        LOGGER.info("Transaction duration: {} ms", duration);
        startTime.remove();
    }
}

